# Is pointwise locally connectedness preserved under a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, locally-connected

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces. $X$ is *locally connected* at $x \in X$, if for each $U \in \mathcal{T}_X(x)$ there exists $U' \in \mathcal{T}_X(x)$ such that $U'$ is connected and $U' \subset U$. Here $\mathcal{T}_X (x)$ denotes the open subsets of $X$ which contain $x$. Let $X$ be locally connected at $x$ and $f : X \to Y$ be a quotient map.

Is $Y$ locally connected at $f(x)$?

#### Notes

- I can prove that the result holds when $f$ is a continuous open map. This includes projection from a product space to its factor.

Comment: So is $X$ locally connected at $x$?

Comment: Yes, added that.

Comment: I doubt that it is true if $X$ is only locally connected at a single point $x$. But it is true if $X$ is locally connected at all points of some neighborhood of $x$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4567646.

Comment: @PaulFrost I also expect it to not hold. The problem is to find a counterexample:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think K. Jiang's answer gives an example which does more than it needs to in order to answer the OP's question  ($X^*$ I think has no locally connected points at all!) .

Let

$$
X = [0,0] \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}] \subseteq [0,1].
$$

Then clearly $1 \in X$ is a point where $X$ is locally connected: if $U\in \mathcal T_X(1)$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon) \cap X \subseteq U$, and thus taking $\epsilon_1 = \min \{\epsilon,1/4 \}$ we see that $V = (1-\epsilon_1,1+\epsilon_1)\cap X \subseteq U$ and $V = (1-\epsilon_1,1]$ is connected.

Now consider the quotient map $q\colon [0,1]\to S^1$ given by identifying $0$ and $1$. It restricts to a quotient map from $X$ to $Y =q(X)$, and because $X$ is compact, the quotient map $q_{|X}$ is even closed. However if we set $e=q(0)=q(1)$, then $Y$ is not locally connected at $e$, despite the fact that $X$ is locally connected at $1$ and $e=q(1)$. Indeed there is no neighbourhood of $e$ in $Y$ which is connected: the reason is just that the same is true of $X$ at $0$ -- any neighbourhood of $0$ contains infinitely many connected components of $X$, and any neighbourhood $V$ of $e$ yields a neighbourhood of both points in $q^{-1}(\{e\})$, and so in particular must be a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Could you add a remark that $Y$ is not even connected im kleinen at $e$, and that $q$ is a closed quotient map?

Comment: I've just edited my answer in a way which I hope addresses the points you raised. Let me know if it would still benefit from a further edit!

Comment: Connected im kleinen means that every neighbourhood of a point contains a connected neighbourhood. Those don't have to be open. Thus it's a weaker property (sometimes it's called weak local connectedness at a point). The point $e$ doesn't even satisfy that

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I didn't know the term "connected im kleinen" before, apologies.

Comment: Thanks:) I'm not sure if it simplifies things, but $X = \{0\} \cup \{1 / n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}\}$ also seems to work.

Comment: But then everyone except 0 is isolated, which seems a bit cruel 0:)

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $Q = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$, and consider the space $X$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual topology) defined as the union of the line segments $L_j$ joining the point $(0, 1)$ to each of the points $(q_j, 0)$, where $q_j \in Q$.

Consider the quotient space $X^*$ formed from $X$ that results by identifying the point $a = (0, 1)$ with the point $b = (0, 0)$; let $p$ be the corresponding quotient map.

While $X$ is locally connected at $a$ (indeed, $a$ is the *only* point at which $X$ is locally connected), the space $X^*$ is not locally connected at $p (a) = \{ a, b \}$, which we presently show.

Consider the open set of $X$ formed by the intersection of $X$ with the union of the two open "balls" $B_\infty \left( a, \frac{1}{4} \right)$ and $B_\infty \left( b, \frac{1}{4} \right)$. Denoting this set as $A$, we note that since $A$ is saturated with respect to $p$ and contains $a$, the image $p (A)$ is a neighborhood of $p (a) = \{ a, b \}$ in $X^*$. We claim that $p (A)$ does not contain a connected neighborhood of $p (a)$.

To show this, consider the (connected) components of $p (A)$. One is $C_0 = p \left( X \cap \left( B_\infty \left( a, \frac{1}{4} \right) \cup \left( \{ 0 \} \times [0, \frac{1}{4}) \right) \right) \right)$. Each of the others can be expressed as $C_k = p \left( X \cap B_\infty \left( b, \frac{1}{4} \right) \cap L_k \right)$, with $L_k$ again representing the segment joining $a$ to $(q_k, 0)$, with $q_k \in Q \backslash \{ 0 \}$, given that the set $C_k$ is non-empty.

Suppose that $V$ is a connected neighborhood of $p (a)$ contained in $p (A)$. Since $V$ is open in $X^*$, its preimage $U = p^{-1} (V)$ must be open in $X$. We know that $a$ is an element of $U$, so there must exist a basis element $B_a = X \cap B_\infty (a, \varepsilon_a > 0)$ contained in $U$. Additionally, $b$ is an element of $U$, so there must exist a basis element $B_b = X \cap B_\infty (b, \varepsilon_b > 0)$ contained in $U$. The set $B_a \cup B_b$ is contained in $U$, and so $p (B_a \cup B_b) = p (B_a) \cup p (B_b)$ is contained in $V$. But $p (B_a)$ intersects $C_0$, while $p (B_b)$ intersects some $C_k \ne C_0$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $V$ is connected.

Comment: If you change this example by instead of $Q$ taking $N = (\{0\}\cup \{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\})\cap [0, 1]$, I believe that $\pi$ is then a map between continua, and $X^*$ is still not connected (even im kleinen) at $\pi(a)$. The property you lose however is that $a$ is not the only point at which $X$ is locally connected anymore.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I think I showed that $X^*$ is not even weakly locally connected at $\pi (a)$, since any neighborhood of $\pi (a)$ that is contained in $\pi (A)$ must intersect $C_0$ as well as some $C_k \ne C_0$ and thus cannot be contained in a single component of $\pi (A)$. I also agree that replacing $Q$ with $N$ as you have defined it suffices for the counterexample.

Comment: Right, if using $N$ instead of $Q$, then $X$ becomes locally connected at all points except those in the set $\{ 0 \} \times [0, 1)$, but the counterexample remains valid.